# Override abstract method, but keep method abstract?

Tags: c#, oop, overriding, abstract

I want to override an abstract method, but keep it abstract so derived classes are required to implement it themselves.

```
public abstract class ComponentController
{
    public abstract void CreateCustomColumns();
}

public abstract class ClientComponentController : ComponentController
{
    public override void CreateCustomColumns()
    {
        // All grids to do with clients should show these columns.
        Grid.AddColumn("Client" ...
        Grid.AddColumn("ClientLocation" ...
        Grid.AddColumn("ClientPhoto" ...
    }
}

public class ClientInvoicesComponentController : ClientComponentController
{
    public override void CreateCustomColumns()
    {
        base.CreateCustomColumns();
        // On top of the generic columns, I also want to show these.
        Grid.AddColumn("InvoiceNumber" ...
        Grid.AddColumn("InvoiceDate" ...
    }
}

public class ClientCommunicationsComponentController : ClientComponentController
{
    public override void CreateCustomColumns()
    {
        base.CreateCustomColumns();
        // On top of the generic columns, I also want to show these.
        Grid.AddColumn("CommunicationDate" ...
        Grid.AddColumn("CommunicationType" ...
    }
}
```

In this code, ClientInvoicesComponentController is not required to implement CreateCustomColumns() because this is not allowed:

```
public abstract class ClientComponentController : ComponentController
{
    public abstract override void CreateCustomColumns()
    {
        Grid.AddColumn("Client" ...
        Grid.AddColumn("ClientLocation" ...
        Grid.AddColumn("ClientPhoto" ...
    }
}

--> "Abstract method cannot declare a body"
```

So, how can I override CreateCustomColumns() in ClientComponentController, but still force it to be overridden again in derived classes like ClientInvoicesComponentController?

Of course it still CAN be overridden anyway, but there is nothing to indicate to the developer that it MUST be overridden... which is my aim.

-Brendan

Comment: I swear this question was asked just a while before. Aaanyways: this is not possible, just make your shared implementation a different method, or use the template method pattern. Clearly if nobody can ever  directly call the implementation `B.A()`, there's no point for it to be an override of a `public abstract` method.

Comment: It might help if you explain a little of exactly what you are trying to do. It looks from here like you are trying to provide a *half-implementation* in class B that derived classes must override but can choose whether to use the base or not, which is quite confusing IMHO. It would really help to see a use-case.

Comment: I've added the use case to the post, if it helps.

Comment: @BrendanHill Near as I can tell there's nothing this would solve that moving the implementation of `ClientComponentController` to a nonabstract protected method wouldn't do. I also don't see much of a reason why the overrides would need to call the base method - it seems that your design is that overriding classes *add* new columns to the grid, so you might as well just always call the base implementation from a constructor.

Comment: @BrendanHill And if you want the overriding classes to have control over whether or not the base class' columns get added or not, you can always expose a collection of column definitions and make this manipulation explicit instead of having it be an artefact of the inheritance chain.

Comment: @BrendanHill Last, but not least, you run into the problem where every override **must** call the base implementation. This is kind of error prone, and C# offers a better way to do this - events. I'd create a protected event called `CreatingColumns` where the event object passes a collection of column definitions to all the listeners. Then child classes may register an event handler in the constructor, or they might not, and this event handler may modify the collection as it sees fit. (The constructor is special in that a base implementation is *always* called.)

Comment: Hi millimoose, sequence of events problems prevent me from triggering the code in the constructor of the intermediate class unfortunately.

I agree though that expecting the derived classes to religiously call base.CreateCustomColumns() is error prone so perhaps my idea is flawed to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think it would be better to divide your logic into 2 methods, one method you play with and the other method your users play with. Assuming the "CreateCustomColumns" method is the name you want your users to override, you create another method, say "CreateCustomColumnsCore", for yourself. The classes may look like this:

```
public abstract class ComponentController
{
    protected abstract void CreateCustomColumnsCore();
}

public abstract class ClientComponentController : ComponentController
{
    protected override void CreateCustomColumnsCore()
    {
        // your code here

        CreateCustomColumns();  // call users' implementation
    }

    public abstract void CreateCustomColumns();
}

public class ClientInvoicesComponentController: ClientComponentController
{
    public override void CreateCustomColumns()
    {
        // user must implement this method.
    }
}
```

Users can still override your CreateCustomColumnsCore method, this could be a feature or a bug based on if you can permit users to do this.

Comment: Thanks Ricky, unfortunately there are "sequence of events" problems which prevent this from being an option, ie. CreateCustomColumns() must be triggered as a specific point in the sequence, rather than the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was intended for the responses above. 

Your suggested option could work as well, except that many classes inherit from the base ComponentController and override CreateCustomColumns() directly. This solution would bring inconsistency between areas as to which needed to be overridden.

Comment: Thanks Ricky - I went with your suggestion in the end, and accepted the minor inconsistency across the program.

Comment: I don't think this is sort of inconsistent. These 2 methods are for 2 different purpose in your case. Alternatively you can keep the method name consistent, but you need to ask your users not to forget calling your base method. I'm not sure if there's a second better choice.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think you really need to force your users to call your base method because they must do, otherwise your users wouldn't get the correct output.

Answer (score 4):

In a word: Not.

A method being abstract means that it is declared but not defined. Being defined but abstract does not really make sense in this context, so it is not possible.

I would also very much like to know your use case. If there is some behaviour you want subclasses to inherit, but also add their own functionality, you could so something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Base class behaviour goes here.
        DoSomethingInternal();
    }

    protected abstract void DoSomethingInternal();
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void DoSomethingInternal()
    {
        // Sub class behaviour goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, I suspected as much. I have updated the post with a use case FYI, in case you have any further ideas.